# Empty tag xml + php + dom

Tags: php, xml, dom

How to assign the tag ref to text?

```
$xml =<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<section name="Section2">
  <category id="category1_of_section2" name="msn">
  teste
   <arti name="article2">value1</arti>
   <arti name="article3">value2 <sref ref="article6" />value6 <sref ref="article7" />value7</arti>
   <arti name="article4">value3 <sref ref="article8" />value8</arti>
  </category>
  <category id="Category2_of_section2" name="webcare">
    <arti name="param3">value4</arti>
  </category>
</section>
</root>
EOT;

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$params = $dom->getElementsByTagName('section'); // Find Sections 
$k=0;
$numero2=0;
$roomStr3="";
foreach ($params as $param)
{
         echo "Section Attribute :-> ".$params->item($k)->getAttribute('name')."<br>";
         $params2 = $params->item($k)->getElementsByTagName('category');
      $i=0;
        foreach ($params2 as $p) 
        {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;- Category Attribute Name :-> ".$params2->item($i)->getAttribute('name')."<br>";
            $params3 = $params2->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('arti');
                $j=0;

                    foreach ($params3 as $p2)
                    {

                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Article Attribute Name : ".$params3->item($j)->getAttribute('name')."";
                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp; Value : ".$params3->item($j)->nodeValue."<br>";

                    var_dump($params3->item($j));
                    $elems3 = $params3->item($j)->getElementsByTagName('sref');

                    $j++;
                    }
        $i++;
      }
$k++;
}
//Print
    Section Attribute :-> Section2
      - Category Attribute Name :-> msn
       - Article Attribute Name : article2   Value : value1
       - Article Attribute Name : article3   Value : value2 value6 value7
       - Article Attribute Name : article4   Value : value3 value8
      - Category Attribute Name :-> webcare
       - Article Attribute Name : param3   Value : value
```

How do I display the ref?

Ex:

- Article Attribute Name : article3   Value : value2 **ref="article6":** value6 **ref="article7":** value7
- Article Attribute Name : article4   Value : value3 **ref="article8":** value8

Comment: can you reduce the code to the relevant portion and also try to explain better what you mean by "how do i display the ref" in context to the title "Assign an empty tag to text xml php"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need the `getAttribute` function to do so.

You have already used it:

```
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Article Attribute Name : ".$params3->item($j)->getAttribute('name')."";
```

Just do the same for the `<sref>`-element:

```
$elems3 = $params3->item($j)->getElementsByTagName('sref');
$elems3Attribute = $elems3->getAttribute('ref');
```